# Not equal to string value not working on postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've written a very simple query

```
select *, "Status" from "ABC" WHERE "ABCId" = 7; // Got 100 rows
```

ABC table has some columns one of them is "Status" with null value usually appearing as (Null)

When I try these queries

```
-- 1
select * FROM "ABC" where "ABCId" = 7 AND "Status" <> 'success'

-- 2
select * FROM "ABC" where "ABCId" = 7 AND "Status" != 'success'

-- 3
select * FROM "ABC" where "ABCId" = 7 AND "Status" NOT ILIKE '%success%'
```

I'm not getting any rows, I bang my head, this is a simple query :/

Comment: `AND status IS NULL`

Comment: No some times it might have the value 'failed' in that case, I should consider null & failed rows too

Comment: Then use an `OR`: `AND status IS NULL OR status <> 'success'`

Comment: what's the wrong with my query it is the basically same right?

Comment: Well, doesn't your experiment show you what the difference is? null is neither = nor <> to anything. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-null-values

Comment: Your query is "basically the same right". Well no. Your mistake is the assumption that logical operations (=, <>=, like, ...) are binary. That is false, they are tertiary or 3-value, they result in the values True, False, or Null. Unforgettably conditionals are binary (basically "when true then else" ) . Example: Given 2 values A and B, Let B be null. Then the test "if A = B" will takes the else option, but "if A != B" also takes the else option, This results because the comparisons both result in NULL. NULL must be handled on it's own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the null safe [comparison operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) `is distinct from`:

```
and "Status" is distinct from 'success'
```

that will be true for null values as well.

Comment: Working, Alternative -> select * FROM "ABC" where "ABCId" = 7 AND COALESCE("Status", '') <> 'success'

Answer (score 0):

Give **coalesce** a try

````
select "ABCId", coalesce(status, 'unknown') from "ABC" where "ABCId" = 7 and ("Status" != 'success' OR status IS NULL);```
````

Comment: @Arjun what number of rows do you get when you try ABCId=7 and Status='success' ?  also what number for when you try ABCId=7 and Status='failure' ?